# Python best practices for storing results in pkl file from concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.map EDITED

Tags: python, dictionary, concurrent.futures

I am writing a genetic algorithm and I was wondering what are some best practices and ideas of how to increase the performance on how to update my results to an external pkl file.

So the **overview** is that I basically have two classes:

- Planning, used to instantiate my problem.

  - Contains my main()
  - Each run of my main() is independent of others and I execute 50 times. So I use the ProcessPoolExecutor here using the map function.

    - Each run of my main() returns me a different Population object
  - After each thread completes one execution I merge the information of the population object to a main population object and export it.
- Population, object containing several numpy arrays attributes.

**Context**
I am looking for some advices on best practices, because I suspect I might have some issues in the way I
am calling the map/merging/exporting my objects in my base case, however I cannot reproduce the behaviour. So I am not sure I might be facing any type of memory issue or I made any other mistake.
Because sometimes, when I know that an execution was ended (Through the print("Finish",num_exec) in the main()) and I know I would:

**Expect**:

1. The print message print("In merge num_chromossomes", pop_main.num_chromossomes)
2. Update in the time of modification of my external pkl file
3. The print message print("Out merge num_chromossomes", pop_main.num_chromossomes)

**Actual**:

1. The print message print("Start",num_exec), printing the next execution.
   So I understand I might be having any issue here.

My **doubts**:

1. Is it a best practice to export, delete, load, merge, export... my external object of the pickle file (As in my run_parallel_export_del_load())? (Because from what I tested it is a bit slower than not doing that)
   Time run_parallel_base 1.034133

   Time run_parallel_export_del_load 1.3652463
2. Is there another best practice for aggregating to a pkl file results from a ProcessPoolExecutor using map?

Many thanks in advance :) !

Here is the minimum example edited leveraging from @wwii comments:

```
import concurrent.futures
import datetime
import pickle
from time import perf_counter
from itertools import product
import numpy as np


class Population:
    """Stores population attributes and methods
    """

    def __init__(self, num_genes, num_chromossomes):
        self.num_chromossomes = num_chromossomes
        # Initializes Batch with 1 batch
        self.batches_raw = np.random.randint(num_chromossomes, size=num_genes)


class Planning:
    # Number of genes
    num_genes = int(25)

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def merge_pop_with_offspring(pop, pop_new):
        """Appends the offspring population to the Current population.

        Args:
            pop (class object): Current Population object
            pop_new (class object): Offspring population object
        """

        pop.batches_raw = np.vstack((pop.batches_raw, pop_new.batches_raw))  # Batches
        pop.num_chromossomes = len(pop.batches_raw)
        return pop

    def main(self, num_chromossomes, num_generations):
        # print("Start",num_exec)
        pop = Population(self.num_genes, num_chromossomes)
        for generation in range(num_generations):
            # Do rest of heavy calculations
            pass
        # print("Finish",num_exec)

        return pop

    def export_obj(self, obj, path):
        with open(path, "wb") as output:  # Overwrites any existing file.
            pickle.dump(obj, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

    def load_obj(self, path):
        with open(path, "rb") as input:
            obj = pickle.load(input)
        return obj

    def run_parallel_base(self):
        """Runs with Multiprocessing.
        """
        # Parameters

        n_exec = 50  # Number of executions
        nc = 100  # Number of Chromossomes
        ng = 1000  # Number of Generations

        root_path = "C:\\Users\\Debora\\Documents\\01_UFU_local\\01_comp_evolutiva\\05_trabalho3\\01_dados\\01_raw\\"

        t0 = perf_counter()
        # Creates a dummy pop with one chromossome to concatenate results
        pop_main = Population(self.num_genes, 1)
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
            for pop_exec in executor.map(self.main, [nc] * n_exec, [ng] * n_exec):
                # print("In merge num_chromossomes", pop_main.num_chromossomes)# Sometimes
                pop_main = self.merge_pop_with_offspring(pop_main, pop_exec)
                # print("Out merge num_chromossomes", pop_main.num_chromossomes)

                file_name = "pop_test.pkl"
                self.export_obj(pop_main, root_path + file_name)
        t1 = perf_counter()
        print("Time run_parallel_base", t1 - t0)

    def run_parallel_export_del_load(self):
        """Runs with Multiprocessing.
        """
        # Parameters

        n_exec = 50  # Number of executions
        n_exec_ite = range(0, n_exec)
        nc = 100  # Number of Chromossomes
        ng = 1000  # Number of Generations

        root_path = "C:\\Users\\Debora\\Documents\\01_UFU_local\\01_comp_evolutiva\\05_trabalho3\\01_dados\\01_raw\\"

        t0 = perf_counter()

        # Creates a dummy pop objects with one chromossome to concatenate results
        pop_main = Population(
            self.num_genes,
            1
        )
        file_name = "pop_test.pkl"
        self.export_obj(pop_main, root_path + file_name)
        del pop_main  # 1)Is it a best practice delete an object after exporting and then load, export and del again?

        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
            for pop_exec in executor.map(self.main, [nc] * n_exec, [ng] * n_exec):
                pop_main = self.load_obj(root_path + file_name)
                # print("In merge num_chromossomes", pop_main.num_chromossomes)
                pop_main = self.merge_pop_with_offspring(pop_main, pop_exec)
                # print("Out merge num_chromossomes", pop_main.num_chromossomes)
                file_name = "pop_test.pkl"
                self.export_obj(pop_main, root_path + file_name)
                del pop_main
                del pop_exec
        t1 = perf_counter()
        print("Time run_parallel_export_del_load", t1 - t0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Planning().run_parallel_base()
    Planning().run_parallel_export_del_load()
```

Comment: You should see if your question is [on topic for Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - if so it may be a better fit over there. You might want to break your post down into separate questions focusing on a single aspect of your query.

Comment: Do all of your functions work in a non-concurrent environment? Have you thouroughly tested them and know that they work?

Comment: `list_vars = list(product(*[nc, ng]))` --> `[(100, 1000)]` : That seems a bit weird , is that what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks for the many insights, just modified it! Regarding the functions, yes all work in non-concurrent and also in concurrent and provide results that are ok in line with a benchmark. I´ve also wrote a bunch of unit tests for the functions, however as always I might have missed something.  What bugs me is that weird behaviour that I can´t reproduce that happens sometimes in one of my last executions, even though that when it happens in the end I still do have the expected shape of aggregated arrays. So I wanted to try to see if there is any best practices that I might have missed.